# Why the absolutely placed element moves up when we scroll down the page and fixed positioned element does not?

Tags: css

When we give an element a position property of absolute with a vertical and horizontal offset (ex bottom, left) it is positioned relative to the closest parent element that has a position property of relative.

If no parent element has a relative property than the absolutely positioned element is positioned with respect to the browser window. 
The definition of fixed positioning is quite the same it says, "Fixed positioning is a type of absolute positioning in which the element is positioned with respect to the browser window."

The main question I have is it that why the absolutely positioned element moves up when the page is scrolled down and the fixed positioned element does not when both of them is placed with respect to the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely positioned elements are never positioned relative to the browser window (i.e. the [viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#viewport)) except by coincidence. Nor are they, in the absence of a positioned ancestor, as w3schools would have it, positioned relative to the body element. Nor are they positioned relative to the html (i.e. the root) element.

```css
html {
  margin:20px;
  border :1px red solid;
  height:100px;
}
body {
  margin:30px;
  border :1px blue solid;
  height:90px;
}
div {
  border :1px green solid;
  height:155px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

If an absolutely positioned element has no positioned ancestor, it is positioned relative to the [initial containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#initial-containing-block), which has its top, left corner at (0, 0) on the [canvas](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/intro.html#the-canvas). As the scrollbars move the viewport over the canvas, so absolutely positioned elements are moved relative to the viewport by scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short explanation of how these positions properties work

**Fixed Position**
A fixed position element is positioned relative to the **viewport**, or the browser window itself. The viewport doesn't change when the window is scrolled, so a fixed positioned element will stay right where it is when the page is scrolled

**Absolute Position**

This property helps to position element with respect to a parent element that has a position of either relative or absolute and if there is no such element it'll position according to the browser window

Answer (score 0):

**Absolute Position:**

An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).
However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

So Basically Absolute Positioning of an Element, when no nearest parent has position defined, Absolute Positioned element is placed with respect to  Element , but not with respect to browser window. that makes it scroll , on scrolling the webpage body or browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, an element with position absolute "is positioned and sized solely in reference to its absolute positioning containing block".

A good follow up question is: what if there is no relative/absolute/fixed positioned parent (including document or body)? The element "is included in the scrollable overflow area of the box that generates is containing block." Usually this is your window object, but it could be any scrollable div you have. Absolutely positioned elements inside of a scrollable element will scroll up with it, even if your scrollable element is statically positioned.

Fixed elements are "positioned relative to ... the viewport" and do  "not move when the document is scrolled."

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#absolute-position